# Clear Angular DropDownList array on close event

Tags: javascript, angular, events, kendo-ui

I have a `kendo-dropdownlist` element in Angular like so:

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist [filterable]="true"
                     [data]="simpleData" [textField]="'name'" [valueField]="'id'"
                     [(ngModel)]="myData.selected"
                     (filterChange)="filterData($event)" required>
 </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

I want to achieve:
Everytime user types, I filter the simpleData on server, if he selects a value from the list, all good;
If he doesn't select a value, I want my simpleData array to reset.

I tried using:
`(close)="onCloseDropDown($event)"`
But the problem is that close event is triggered before selectionChange event so I can't do:

```
  onCloseDropDown(event: any) {
    if(this.myData.selected == null) { 
      this.simpleArticles = []
    }
  }
```

Because myData.selected is not yet updated.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `this. simpleData = []`

Answer (score 0):

AS per documentation of [Kendo UI for Angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/) the Blur Event will be execute in last. So, currently what You are trying to achieve! this **blur()** event will help you,

Please modify your html code by adding this part within kendo-dropdownlist component

```
(blur)="blur()"
```

or replace your html code with below code

```
<kendo-dropdownlist 
  [filterable]="true"
  [data]="simpleData" 
  [textField]="'name'" 
  [valueField]="'id'"
  [(ngModel)]="myData.selected"
  (filterChange)="filterData($event)" 
  (blur)="blur()" <!-- I have added this Blur Event Here -->
  required>
 </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Inside your component.ts file, define blur method

```
blur() {
  // Execute your statements or anything else that you want to achieve.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Face the same problem but after some research I able to resolved this

**Step 1: give reference to your list**

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [filterable]="true"
                     #dropList
                     [data]="simpleData" [textField]="'name'" 
                     [valueField]="'id'"
                     [(ngModel)]="myData.selected"
                     (filterChange)="filterData($event)" required>
```

**Step 2: use a ViewChild for using this reference**

```
@ViewChild('dropList') dropList: DropDownListComponent;
```

**step 3: using this ViewChild and call reset method of dropdown**

```
onCloseDropDown(event: any) {
    if(this.myData.selected == null) { 
      this.dropList.reset();
    }
  }
```

Hope this will help someone